# Dynamically Add json object to Sencha selectfield?

Tags: javascript, json, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a json object which. How can I add this to sencha selectfield?

```
{

   "info":{
      "sd-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1f9f":"root",
      "sd-8d30-11e2-98f5-bf6df0e83168":"WS123",
      "sd-8d31-11e2-956a-8f722b3d14b8":"test"
   }
}
```

Code for Adding items to selectfield

```
 {

                        xtype: 'selectfield',
                        autoLoad: true,

                        label:'Parent category',
                        name: 'parent_uuid',

                        options : [


                            {text: 'Select category',  value: 'select'},
                            {text: 'Root',  value: 'sd-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1f9f'}
    ]

}
```

How can I convert my json object to this format   `{text: 'Root',  value: 'sd-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1f9f'}`

Comment: Not sure why you tagged the question with jQuery, but you should not use both jQuery and Sencha frameworks in a same application. It's too heavy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
var json = {
   "info":{
      "sd-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1f9f":"root",
      "sd-8d30-11e2-98f5-bf6df0e83168":"WS123",
      "sd-8d31-11e2-956a-8f722b3d14b8":"test"
   }
},
    options = [],
    i;

for (i in json.info) {
  options.push({text: json.info[i], value: i})
}
```

Then you just need to get your select field and user the `add` function to add options

```
selectfield.add(options);
```

Hope this helped

Comment: The data formatting is working, but How can I get instance of my selectfield?  I tried this in initialize:function() but got error var category_selectfield = document.getElementById('category_selectfield');
                        category_selectfield.add(formattedJSON);    



Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of null

Comment: got it. it's not add but selectfield.setOptions(options); Thanks man